# How to delete selected rows from array of object in Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have table which contain multiple rows.

I want to delete selected rows from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the array from the last when removing elements.

```
for (let i = this.StaticData.selected_parameter_value.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (this.staticValuemodel.rowsSelected[i] === true) {
    this.StaticData.selected_parameter_value.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: No i dont want to sort, i want to find key from array [
      0:false,
      1:true,
      3:true,
      4:true
  ] whose values are true..and need to delete element from array this.StaticData.selected_parameter_value

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass the index of the particular row in the function like

html file////

<tr *ngFor="let row of YOUR_ARRAY;let i=index;" (click)="deleteRow(i)">
    <td>col</td>
</tr>

Ts File////

deleteRow(index): void {
    this.YOUR_ARRAY.splice(index, 1);
}
```